# wavefunction and contextuality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, specific-reference

According to the French philosopher [Michel Bitbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Bitbol), the "*deep-lying connection between the contextual character of observables, and the wave-like form of probability distributions was demonstrated mathematically by P. Destouches-Février [1956]*" (See page 7 of [this article](http://michel.bitbol.pagesperso-orange.fr/ConsciousnessSituatQM.pdf)). Unfortunately I cannot find the [1956's book](http://www.amazon.fr/LInterpretation-physique-mecanique-ondulatoire-quantiques/dp/B001856IMU/) cited in the article.

Does any of you know this result (or a similar one)? Where I can find it reproduced?

Comment: @Danu: Please feel free to improve my question.

Comment: You might want to post this on a philosophy site. Physics does not care about philosophy. Honestly, as soon as I saw that the article began with mentioning "consciousness", I was done reading. That's just another person wasting their mind on an ill-defined problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne: In fact, I only mentioned this article because this is where I found the reference to the book. But the book is a *physics* book written by a *physicist*.

Comment: @Bob: I certainly never heard of that book before and even if I had, I don't speak French, so I wouldn't have read it. What might be interesting about it is that Messier Destouches-Février may have had been a little bit ahead of others who had similar ideas and maybe he is one of the forgotten greats of physics who didn't get credit because their contributions were never properly advertised. Now that I would find interesting, far more so than the consciousness thing.